# Known KB Questions

Tags: windows

I am working on some code to compare known KBs installed on a machine to all released KBs from Microsoft.

Google is not being friendly tonight and I can not find what I am looking for, can anyone tell me where I may find a list of all known KBs that Microsoft has released per OS?  This way I just need to make a dif of what is installed v. what is not.

Comment: There's a link [here](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/) that talks about an API for retrieving security update information.  That might also give you, e.g., the information about update supersedence that you'll probably need.  I've never used it, and the link won't let me in for some reason, but perhaps it will prove useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the list of the most common versions of Windows and Windows Server. The keyword to google is [Windows Version] update history. I check these websites after microsoft releases an update. Very helpful info to have especially if you release updates via WSUS.

[Windows 10 (All Builds), Server 1709, Windows Server 2016 and Server 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043454/windows-10-windows-server-update-history)

[Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009470/windows-8-1-windows-server-2012-r2-update-history)

[Windows 7 SP1 And Server 2008 R2 SP 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009469/windows-7-sp1-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-update-history)

Comment: Also https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV990001 and I think there are still one-off updates released occasionally as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Update Catalogue](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/) can offer a way to find all the KB per OS, but you might have to search with the correct term.